# Unable to login as a newly created user

Tags: users, kali-linux

I have a dual boot Kali Linux along with windows 7.  Now when I installed Kali it logs me in as root.  I do not have a login in my name.  So I created a user with the following steps.  However when I log off and login, there is an " Authentication Failure" with the new login.  Where am I going wrong?

```
 laa@aa-lu:~$ sudo useradd testinguser
    alaa@aa-lu:~$ sudo passwd testinguser
    Enter new UNIX password:
    Retype new UNIX password:
    passwd: password updated successfully
    alaa@aa-lu:~$ sudo ls -l /home
    total 20
    drwxr-xr-x 55 alaa alaa  4096 Aug 22 22:00 alaa
    drwx------  2 root root 16384 Jun  5 09:46 lost+found
    alaa@aa-lu:~$ sudo mkdir /home/testinguser
    alaa@aa-lu:~$ sudo chown testinguser:testinguser /home/testinguser
    alaa@aa-lu:~$ ls -l /home
    total 24
    drwxr-xr-x 55 alaa        alaa         4096 Aug 22 22:00 alaa
    drwx------  2 root        root        16384 Jun  5 09:46 lost+found
    drwxr-xr-x  2 testinguser testinguser  4096 Aug 23 10:03 testinguser
    alaa@aa-lu:~$ ls -l /home/testinguser/
    total 0
    alaa@aa-lu:~$
```

Comment: Are there any errors in `/var/log/auth.log`?

Comment: what the `grep testinguser /etc/passwd` output?

Comment: Jul 11 18:39:39 kali gdm3][3693]: pam_unix(gdm3:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=:1 ruser= rhost=  user=testinguser

Comment: testinguser:x:1000:1001::/home/testinguser:/bin/sh

Comment: 1000:1001 is strange.

Comment: You should really consider accepting answers that you feel are helpful, or at least up-vote them.

Answer (score 2):

`useradd` only copies the content of `/etc/skel` when you set the `-m` option to create the home directory and use the `-k` option.

You have to do that manually now with `cp /etc/skel/.[a-z]* /home/testinguser/`. Don't forget to set correct owner of the files:

`chown -R testinguser:testinguser /home/testinguser`

In Debian based systems `adduser` is easier to use, as it uses more defaults and runs interactively.

The 1000:1001 disparity seems problematic.

Give the results of

`grep '1000\|1001\|testinguser\|alaa' /etc/passwd`

and

`grep '1000\|1001\|testinguser\|alaa' /etc/group`

to see what happened there.

Then set the password to something unproblematic like "456" to rule out this problem.

Comment: It still gives authentication failure

Comment: I added the chmod and the password rule out.

Comment: thank you that seems to have worked, but is there a good source where I can know why I need to do the 2 greps you mentioned

Comment: The greps did not solve something. It was just for getting information about your problem. I was asking you to post the results of the greps.

Comment: grep '1000\|1001\|testinguser\|alaa' /etc/group
testinguser:x:1000:1001::/home/testinguser:/bin/sh

grep '1000\|1001\|testinguser\|alaa' /etc/group
inetsim:x:1000:
testinguser:x:1001: